# Adjusting the size of HAXM emulator

Tags: android, emulation

While start the emulator the following error is coming-:

```
                C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -scale 0.25 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Hari_API_22
                emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
                emulator: device fd:680
                HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
                emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
                emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
                emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
                emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
                creating window 36 48 271 482
                emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Can somebody tell how to configure the RAM size of HAXM emulator.

Comment: Re-run the HAXM installer and it'll let you choose, I think, but I've not done it for a while and only then on OS X.

Comment: which u used Android Studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: you can follow want Matt Gibson suggested alternatively you can edit the emulator and change the value of the RAM assigned to it from 1024 to 512